# Why can I not insert numerical values into a MS Access Database through an sql query in c# windows form?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I used the following code to insert data into a database

```
public partial class Products : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    public Products()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Folder\Database.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    }
private void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, Quantity, Weight(g)) VALUES ('" + txtName.Text + "', '" + txtQuantity.Text + "', '" + txtWeight.Text + "')";
            
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved");
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
        

    }
```

And the last two variables don't seem to work. I tried entering a string for the first field and it works perfectly, but when I go to insert a number on the last two variables it throws an exception. I've already tried doing int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the exception? Edit question to show exact message. Don't use apostrophe delimiters for number field parameter (use # for date/time). Or use declared parameters instead of concatenation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work.

Comment: Use Command [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_OleDb_OleDbParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_OleDb_OleDbType_System_Int32) to build the query, don't (try to) concatenate strings. It will also solve data Type mismatches. -- Write your Fields in square brackets.

Comment: Square brackets are only necessary if object name uses spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) or are reserved words. However, using can't hurt.

Comment: Sorry the exception says 
"ErrorSystem.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. 
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NUmberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) 
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
at Database.Products.cmdAdd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
C:Folder.cs:line 58

Comment: Square brackets are obviously necessary here, `Weight(g)` contains parentheses and that's not allowed so needs to be bracketed. However, there are a ton of other red flags here, such as the risk of SQL injection and use of Access + ASP.Net which is explicitly not supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Change your string by removing ' from the last 2 items:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, Quantity, Weight(g)) 
VALUES ('" + txtName.Text + "', " + txtQuantity.Text + ", " + txtWeight.Text + ")";
```

Comment: I have taken out apostrophes and it still gives me a similar exception